# preg_replace заменить ближайшее вхождение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть выражение:
`<xx></xx><xx><tt>ZZZ</tt></xx>`

Необходимо произвести замену с помощью pref_replace 
`<xx><tt>ZZZ</tt></xx>`

Если произвести замену по выражению
`/<xx>.*ZZZ.*<\/xx>/`

то заменится вся строка. Как заменить только нужное?

Пробовал выражение 
`/<xx>(?!.*xx).*ZZZ.*<\/xx>/`, но оно не дает никаких результатов.
Подскажите как быть в этой ситуации?

Comment: добавьте вопросы в выражение (ленивый захват) `.*?` ну и обозначьте как то искомый участок так, что бы это отличало от других похожих участков, что бы первые XX не попали под выражение

Comment: Приведите пример: что дано, что надо получить. Две строки.

Comment: Дано `123 <xx></xx><xx><tt>ZZZ</tt></xx> 123`, надо получить например `123 <xx></xx><pp>OOO</pp> 123`, т.е. заменить `<xx><tt>ZZZ</tt></xx>` на нужное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вам нужна такая регулярка

```
/<xx>((?!<\/xx>).)*?ZZZ((?!<xx>).)*?<\/xx>/
```

После нахождения `<xx>` при просмотре каждого последующего символа проверяет отсутствие `</xx>` и наличие `ZZZ`. После нахождения `ZZZ` при просмотре каждого последующего символа проверяет отсутствие `<xx>` и наличие `</xx>`.

Пример работы https://regex101.com/r/6nbyxX/1

P.S. Возможно стоит заменить `(?!<\/xx>)` и `(?!<xx>)` на `(?!<\/?xx>)`.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

```
123 <xx></xx><xx><tt>ZZZ</tt></xx> 123
```

заменить на

```
123 <xx></xx><pp>OOO</pp> 123
```

Возможно, достаточно:

```
$s = preg_replace('@<xx><tt>ZZZ</tt></xx>@us', '<pp>OOO</pp>');
```